# CE1.9.2.4 - how to remove column from Customer Adminhtml Grid

Tags: adminhtml, ce-1.9.2.4, custom-grid

I've successfully extended the core Customer Grid to show some custom attributes, but also need to remove the `Country` column - the site in question only operates in one country, so it's unnecessary and takes up space on smaller screens.

I've tried:

```
protected function _prepareColumns(){
    $this->removeColumn('billing_country_id'); // <---- this does not work :(
    $this->addColumnAfter('department', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Department'),
        'index'     => 'department'
    ),'email');

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
```

but this does not seem to work. Is there another method that I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the column doesn't work because at the moment when you are calling the `removeColumn` method, the `billing_country_id` column hasn't been added yet. That column gets added when `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid::_prepareColumns` is called, and that happens at the end of your method. You can try something like this:

```
protected function _prepareColumns() {
    parent::_prepareColumns();
    $this->removeColumn('billing_country_id'); // <--- hopefully this will work :)
    $this->addColumnAfter('department', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Department'),
        'index'     => 'department'
    ), 'email');
    $this->sortColumnsByOrder();
    return $this;
}
```

I've also added the `sortColumnsByOrder` method call at the end in order to sort the newly added column too.